# Facebook API - Does the domain of the app needs to be the definitive one for reviewing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't directly contact the Facebook developper support, so I ask it here for those who have already validate their application.

I need to submit my Facebook application for reviewing, and I have a pre-production domain to access it but my production domain will be different than the pre-production (which is not yet accessible).

So, if I submit my application for review on the pre-production domain (and if Facebook valid it), will the application still be valid on my production domain ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Review is tied to the app id; domain settings don’t matter, you can change them at any time.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your answer, I wanted to be sure ! You can post it as an answer if you want me to solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review is tied to the app id; domain settings don’t matter, you can change them at any time.

Changing domains does not require a re-submission for review.

Comment: Another question (nothing relates to my initial question) : I can retrieve user location (city, country and region) but not his address (street) and zip. Did you ever tried to access it ? Or Facebook doesn't give the possibility to access it ?

Comment: No, the user’s address is not available via API.